# Any way to tie an animation curve to particles' age?

Tags: animation, particles, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm working on a scene that requires the animation curve of the halo material's alpha value to be tied to the particles' age, so the particles can fade over time. Is there a way to pull that effect off in Blender 2.7???

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this (i am pretty sure this works on blender 2.7 too...but i did it on Blender 3.0)

[image]

[image]

The particle age is in frames, so as you can see at frame 100 alpha is 0, and at frame 0 alpha is 1.

That't why i multiplicate the frame with 0.01 (which is 1 for frame 100), but i want alpha to be 0 so i subtract (1 - thatValue) so i get 1 at frame 1 and 0 at frame 100.

```
Note: the particle info node with age does only work with cycles
```

---

```
Note: The age of a particle is since the particle was emitted so it's emission_frame + 100 in my example, and because emission_frame is 0 it is as a wrote above.
```

Comment: Note that the age of a particle is since the particle was emitted so it's emission_frame + 100 in your example.

Comment: I'm using Blender Internal on 2.7. Is there a way to make particles fade over time in that configuration?

Comment: works only for cycles: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaFTr.png

Comment: i think it should be possible with animation nodes....

Comment: I currently don't have Animation Nodes installed on my instance of Blender 2.7. Is there any way to make halo particles fade over time in Blender Internal without using Animation Nodes?

Comment: as i said: works only on cycles...so: no